# Can I get a high quality image from a rostrum mounted camera and bounce flash?

Tags: lighting, image-quality, document-reproduction, bounce-flash

I have some approximately A3 sized documents I need to scan but don't have access to an A3 scanner and it's beyond my budget to purchase one. However, I can probably run to a rostrum stand for my [Canon EOS 450D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_EOS_450D).

Would this setup with a bounce flash attached to the camera produce a high enough quality image to be able to read the documents? I've done a quick calculation based on the resolution of the camera - 2,848 x 4,272 pixels and A3 paper size - 11.7 x 16.5 in which gives a dpi of 243 x 258 which *might* be enough to be legible.

I believe, therefore, that the issue comes down to the lighting. I know that rostrum stands are usually used with lights, but these add to the cost for what is effectively a one off job, so I'd like to do without them if at all possible.

Comment: Yes it is good enough in terms of resolution. Use the longer focal leingth you have. Try to bounce not just one but at least 2 sides. Try not to bounce from the camera side but at 45 degree angle.

Comment: @Rafael can you add an answer that shows how I'd bounce on two side without extra lights?